# Python Error in syntax with MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

This is my script

```
 cur.execute("CREATE TABLE +dnes+ (Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, \
                 Name VARCHAR(25))")
```

I'm trying put the variable dnes into the this query. The variable is string.
It's not working. It says:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+dnes+ (Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, Name VARCHAR(25))' at line 1")
```

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: What makes you think adding plus signs inside a string inserts variables in Python? You can't just invent syntax.

Comment: I thought that it merge the strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using string concatenation; the `+` is part of the string, not Python syntax.

You probably meant to do this:

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE " + dnes + " (Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, "
            "Name VARCHAR(25))")
```

You could use string formatting instead:

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE {0} (Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, "
            "Name VARCHAR(25))".format(dnes))
```

If you need to create table names that use special characters or reserver words, or consist solely of digits, you'll need to quote the name:

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE `{0}` (Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, "
            "Name VARCHAR(25))".format(dnes))
```

See the [*Schema Object Names* documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html).

Comment: Yes I meant this ! Thank you :) And one last question.
My variable looks: dnes = time.strftime('%d%m%Y')
A Pythons says _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '040814 (Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,Name VARCHAR(25))' at line 1")

Comment: @Tomas: Why in heavens name are you trying to use date strings as table names in the first place? Those are not valid identifiers, not without additional quoting.